Testing navigations in Next with Jest
I am trying to test that my navigations work properly but my test keep failing.
This is my Home component
import Link from "next/link";

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div className="bg-bgDefault font-switzer h-screen w-full flex flex-row justify-center items-center m-auto space-x-10">
      <div>
        <Link href="/signup">
          <button>Sign up</button>
        </Link>
      </div>
      <div>
      <Link href="signIn">
          <button>Log in</button>
      </Link>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}


This is my test code.
jest.mock('next/router', () => ({
  useRouter: jest.fn()
}));

describe ('Navigation works', () => {
  it('navigates to the correct route on click', () => {
    const push = jest.fn();
    useRouter.mockImplementation(() => ({
      push,
    }));

    render(<Home />);

    const signUpButton = screen.getByText('Sign up');
    const logInButton = screen.getByText('Log in');

    // Simulate clicks
    signUpButton.click();
    logInButton.click();

    // Check if the push method was called with the correct arguments
    expect(push).toHaveBeenCalledWith('href', '/signup');
    expect(push).toHaveBeenCalledWith('href', '/signIn');
  });
});

This is the error I am getting
Navigation works › navigates to the correct route on click

    expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...expected)

    Expected: "href", "/signup"

    Number of calls: 0

      58 |
      59 |     // Check if the push method was called with the correct arguments
    > 60 |     expect(push).toHaveBeenCalledWith('href', '/signup');
         |                  ^
      61 |     expect(push).toHaveBeenCalledWith('href', '/signIn');
      62 |   });
      63 | });

      at Object.toHaveBeenCalledWith (__tests__/Home.test.tsx:60:18)


I have tried to read the documentations and can't seem to get what exactly is making the test to fail.
